# rails state_machine : How do I trigger an action on :initial state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

This is what I have:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :open do
    after_transition :on => :buy, :do => :send_buy_notification_email
    after_transition :on => :take, :do => :send_take_notification_email
    after_transition :on => :accept, :do => :send_accept_notification_email
    after_transition :on => :cancel, :do => :send_cancel_notification_email
```

Now I'd like to trigger :send_trade_notification_email on the initial state open.

How do I do that?

Cheers,

Joel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the state transitions are analogous to the 'usual' AR callbacks, perhaps your method should be triggered in the after_create callback?  After all, your transition is from nil to open which would happen on create:

```
 after_create :send_trade_notification_email
```

Which, if it were allowed, would accomplish the same thing as:

```
 after_transition :on=>:create, :do=>:send_trade_notification_email
```

Comment: Does this mean that `after_transition` can apply to `:create` and `:update`?

Comment: It's honestly crazy that the syntax you provided is not allowed.  Seems like basic functionality for something so standard.

Answer (score 0):

i have found another approach

```
def initial_send_trade_notification_email
  send_trade_notification_email #do what you need on create
  :open # return initial state
end

state_machine initial: lambda(&:initial_send_trade_notification_email) do
  #...
end
```